# Is Guantánamo Bay, Cuba open to visitors/tourists?

Tags: cuba, military

Okay, I know this sounds crazy, but I was wondering if Guantánamo was open to tourists. I have read it is not possible in some forums, but again, those are forums. Wikitravel says that "Non-US, non-military personnel have been to the base."

So is there a definitive answer?

Comment: I met someone the other day who had been to the Guantanamo prison camp a number of times, but she was a card-carrying journalist (non-US and non-military).

Comment: It's easy to get there... just threaten to bomb your local U.S. Embassy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While I initially laughed at the idea, apparently [there might be](http://wikitravel.org/en/Guant%C3%A1namo_Bay#By_land):

> Hotel Islazul, Guantánamo city may be able to arrange tours to the
>   American military for around $40 though this service is not always
>   available.

It does seem to be a long shot though. It's a US Military base, which generally means off limits unless you're enlisted, family, or have an invitation.

Certainly there is [evidence of media tours](http://www.aljazeera.com/humanrights/2013/06/20136197533407379.html), if you're a journalist or in a related field you may have a better chance.  But it sounds like Hotel Islazul might be your best shot - perhaps contact them when you arrive.  According to [CubaWeb](http://www.cubaweb.cu/en/jardines-del-rey?page=shop.product_details&flypage=flypage.tpl&product_id=464&category_id=139), their contact details would be:

> Hotel Islazul Guantánamo
>
> ** Address: Ahogados y 13 Norte, Guantánamo.
>
> Phones. (5321) 38 1015 / 38 2535 / 38 4555
>
> Email.  recephotel@hotelgtmo.co.cu

Comment: Applying my marketingspeak translator, and tour *to* a base is not necessarily the same as going *on* a base.

Comment: @DJClayworth indeed, but if anyone *can* do it, that's going to be the most likely, I think.  Aside from getting a one-way pass in, of course.

Comment: I agree with you Mark. I just wanted to warn the questioner.

Comment: @MarkMayo Can you find contact info for the hotel? I can't seem to track anything down. I'd like to e-mail so I can ask in advance first.

Comment: From my understanding from friends who went there - places in Cuba often don't have email :/  I'll have a hunt tho

Comment: Aha, found it! Will update answer.

Comment: Needing an invitation doesn't mean you can't visit. Otherwise we would have very few questions on Russia and a bunch of other countries... Maybe we should check out what possibilities exist for invitations?

Comment: I suppose the tour goes near the place but not into the place... by the way there are several levels of wire fences, cactus and mine-fields between Cuban territory and the base.